# clear the URL from $_GET then display a warning message after update

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

The point is to change the user status (active/inactive) from a button, clear the URL from all GET and then display a warning message from bootstrap

Here the url: `http://localhost:8282/userslist.php?deactive=59`

What I mean by clear: `http://localhost:8282/userslist.php`

Display the warning message:

[image]

I'm able to clear the URL with a `location.href='userslist.php'` but my warning message is not displayed (because the refresh hide the message), or, I'm able to display the warning message but I can't clear the URL. I tried to do it separatly with two echo but without any success.

The button to active/inactive an user are:

`http://localhost:8282/userslist.php?deactive=52`
`http://localhost:8282/userslist.php?active=52`

My code is

```
if (isset($_GET['deactive'])) {
    $deactive = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', (int)$_GET['deactive']);
    userDeactiveByAdmin($conn, $deactive, $_SESSION["users_uid"]);
    $getProfile = getProfile($conn, $deactive);
    $username = $getProfile["users_uid"];
    //echo "<script>location.href='userslist.php';</script>";
    echo "<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show text-center' role='alert'>User <strong>\"$username\"</strong> inactive with success
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>";
}
```

My function is

```
function userDeactiveByAdmin($conn, $id, $username)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET isActive = 1, updated_by = '$username' WHERE users_id = $id;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I don't know how can I do both (clear the URL and display the warning message).

Comment: I think just a little jquery would be the simplest solution.  Take a look at this https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-remove-query-string-from-urlexample.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common approach, since you're already using `$_SESSION` values, is to use a `header()` redirect and compare against a separate session variable instead of the `$_GET` variable.

The end-result is that the page will appear to quickly reload after performing the desired action (`userDeactiveByAdmin()`) removing the querystring in the URL and then display the message based on the supplied `$_SESSION` value.

This also can be converted to change the processing page URL to implement separation of concerns, such as `/deactivate.php?user=59` instead of using `/userlist.php?deactive=59`.

I recommend using [`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) and/or [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions to sanitize and validate the input data with the desired filter options. This will ensure you are not accepting unexpected values.

```php
$deactive = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'deactive', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if (false !== $deactive) {
   userDeactiveByAdmin($conn, $deactive, $_SESSION["users_uid"]);
   $_SESSION['deactive'] = $deactive;
   header('Location: /userlist.php');
   exit;
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['deactive'])) {
    $deactive = filter_var($_SESSION['deactive'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    unset($_SESSION['deactive']);

    if (false !== $deactive) {
        $username = getProfile($conn, $deactive)["users_uid"];

        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show text-center' role='alert'>User <strong>\"$username\"</strong> inactive with success
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
</button>
</div>";
    }
}
```

---

The above can also be adapted to store the username or entire message you want to display.

```php
$deactive = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'deactive', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if (false !== $deactive) {
   userDeactiveByAdmin($conn, $deactive, $_SESSION["users_uid"]);

   $username = getProfile($conn, $deactive)["users_uid"];
   $_SESSION['warning'] = "User <strong>\"$username\"</strong> inactive with success";

   header('Location: /userlist.php');
   exit;
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['warning'])) {
    $warning = $_SESSION['warning'];
    unset($_SESSION['warning']);

    echo "<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show text-center' role='alert'>$warning
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
</button>
</div>";
}
```

---

Regarding `$deactive = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', (int)$_GET['deactive']);`.
You only really need `$deactive = (int)$_GET['deactive'];`.
However, since type-casting `(int) "-";` or any non-numeric value will result in 0, I strongly advise using `filter_input` or `filter_var` instead with the desired filter options, which will result in `false` when an unexpected value is supplied. Example: https://3v4l.org/YfCOH